# Как считывать изменения трансляции геопозиции в telegram-bot-sdk

Tags: php, telegram, бот, location

Подскажите. Как считывать трансляцию, изменения геопозоции, отправленные пользователем боту?
User -> Трансляция геопозиции -> Telegram bot -> как прочиать изменения?

Отправленное сообщение с трансляцией код обрабатывает, но только первые отправленные данные (интересуют долгота, широта).

Использую: telegram-bot-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено, за это отвечает команда:
$message = $this->update->getEditedMessage()

Описание здесь: https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.editMessage